# Google Analytics API returning Inaccessible Arrays

Tags: php

A call to analytics returns users and new users, in a form where both figures are there, but I can't figure out how to address them. Print_r returns the following:

$row

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(3) "722" 
    } 
} 
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "6608" 
    } 
}
```

$row[0]

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "722" 
} 
array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(4) "6608" 
}
```

$row[0][0]

```
string(3) "722" string(4) "6608"

gettype($row[0][0])
stringstring
```

It's as if there's 2 strings in one array cell.

I've dumped the output in various ways and gotten the type which is apparently stringstring.

```
function initializeAnalytics()
{   
  // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';
  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
  return $analytics;
}

function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
  // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

  // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
  $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
  if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
    $items = $accounts->getItems();
    $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();
    // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
    $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);
    if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
      $items = $properties->getItems();
      $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();
      // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
      $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
          ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);
      if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $profiles->getItems();
        // Return the first view (profile) ID.
        return $items[0]->getId();
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}

function getNewVsReturning($analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
  // Run from last monday to today
  $today = date('Y-m-d');
  $lastmonday=strtotime('previous monday', strtotime($today));
  $lastmonday=date('Y-m-d',$lastmonday);
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       "$lastmonday",
       'today',
       array('ga:users','ga:newUsers'));
}

  function parseNewVsReturning($results) {
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

      // Get the profile name.
      $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

      // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
      $rows = $results->getRows();
      $sessions = $rows[0][0];

      // Print the results.
      return $sessions;
    } else {
      return "Something went bad";
    }
  }

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$newVsReturning=getNewVsReturning($analytics,$profile);
$record['newVsReturning'] = parseNewVsReturning($newVsReturning);
```

I would expect to see something where I can address the 2 pieces of data like

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "722",
    [1]=> string(4) "6608" 
}
```

Comment: Thats not even the output from a `print_r()`

Comment: Forgot to add the output of echo $row[0][0] - it's 7226608. I've used print_r, var_dump and echo.